# Should I separate single and multiplayer game modes into different Android activities?

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been developing a turn-based game, which has both single player and (local) multiplayer options. The gameplay is largely similar between the two apart from the fact that CPU controls one of the turns in single player.

Is it wise to make a separate Android activity for both options or make one activity which handles both via booleans etc?

Comment: Personally I would probably make them as separate activities. It is likely that different things will cause them to break. Thus having it all in one activity might make it harder to fix when something does break.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was just worried about mass code duplication (same code in both activities for the most part) being bad practice. Is this an issue? Particularly since mobile platforms rely on small memory etc

Comment: It depends on exactly how much needs to change. A better solution might be to move the game logic from the Activities into its own GameHelper object or something. Then have both activities make use of this object. The memory won't be an issue. The first few android devices released had very small chunks of "internal storage" for applications. More modern devices all tend to have a plethora, and users have the option to move apps to the SD card now if they want. Plus the size of a single java file should be nearly negligible. Your app icon probably takes up more than most of the Java files.

Comment: Yep I think I'll just make two separate activities. It is only a relatively small game therefore code duplication of the whole activity shouldn't be an issue (< 10kb probably). Thanks again for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is have a library or helper classes that contain the ground for both activities and then have the two different activities (One for single and one for multiplayer) this way you don't need to duplicate the code and its only there once. Also with this its easier to fix if something goes wrong.

For debugging you should have different log tags for each activity and put try things around all the things that need it and log the errors with their log tags.

According to oracle you should keep your java files under 2000 lines of code as well, so if it goes over this definitely split them up.

Comment: I dont necessarily agree.  I think this is a preference.  I dont think there really is an answer to this question, simply a preference.  I developed a game for iPhone / iPad that used a single OpenGL view and implemented all the mode code myself, and it works just fine.  I would architect it the same way on Android.

Comment: Yes but it would be better to have another class where all the functions are so that you don't replicate it, it would make things faster and also easier to debug